# KendoListView, scroll to top, Is this possible?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoListview that has to scroll to top, in buttom pagination (pageNumbers) is clicked and it should to go to top of the page

please let me know how can i achive.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing a `window.scrollTo(0,0)` in the `dataBound` event:

```
dataBound: function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Check it here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/Odebi/2

Answer (score 0):

I found a function for this, in Kendo mobile MVVM

```
parent.set('onShow', function (e) {
   e.view.scroller.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the KendoPager, this will do what you need to do.

In the page, you will probably have your KendoListView and KendoPager declared something like this:

```
<ul id="results" class="list-group list-group-flush"></ul>
<div id="resultsPager" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
```

In the JavaScript, when you initialize the KendoPager, wire up a `change` event something like this:

```
$("#resultsPager").kendoPager({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    change: resultsPager_OnPageChanged
}).data("kendoPager");
```

When the page is changed it will then call the resultsPager_OnPageChanged funtion which is this:

```
function resultsPager_OnPageChanged()
{
    $("#results").scrollTop(0);
}
```

This scrolls the KendoListView content back to the top.